# Getting a single result with angularjs factory in MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to grab a single result from my expressjs api from within my AngularJS factory.

The factory looks like this and grabs all posts from my api(written in expressjs and getting data from mongodb), which is working fine:

```
angular.module('bonsaiService', ['ngResource']).
factory('bonsaiService', function($q,$resource) {
    var bonsaiResource = $resource('http://localhost:8888/api/bonsais/:bonsaiId',{},{
        get:{
            method: 'GET',
            params:{bonsaiId:''},
            isArray: true
        }
    });
    return {
        get:function(){
            var q = $q.defer();
            bonsaiResource.get({

            },
            function(resp){
                q.resolve(resp);
            },function(httpResponse){
                q.reject(httpResponse);
            });
            return q.promise;
        }
        //find by id
    };
});
```

What i've tried so far is adding :bonsaiId after the $resource url and adding params for that id like this: params:{bonsaiId: ''}.

The server part (expressJS) look like this:

```
router.route('/bonsais/:bonsaiId')
.get(function(req,res){
        Bonsai.findOne(req.params.bonsaiId,function(err,bonsai){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(bonsai)
        })
    })
```

When I call a local url (with and existing _id from mongodb) it works fine and returns my data in json :

```
http://localhost:8888/api/bonsais/536be2e2ae54668818000001
```

Now in the controller im trying to get this data in my scope, which is not working.

```
    bonsaiService.get({bonsaiId:$routeParams.bonsaiId}).then(
    function(data){
        $scope.trees = data;

        console.log(data);
});
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: What happens in your console when you call your service ? Also, have you injected the service in your controller (or in your entire app, via the config) ?

Comment: I get a result of all the entries in the mongodb...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more simple approach here.

The [query method for $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) already defines a `GET` on an array, which is `QUERY`.

Why not write your service this way :

```
.factory('bonsaiService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8888/api/bonsais/:bonsaiId', {
            bonsaiId: '@bonsaiId'
        });
    }
])
```

And in your controller, it would work like this :

```
bonsaiService.query({
    bonsaiId: $routeParams.bonsaiId
}, function success() {
    //Your code
}, function err() {
    //Your code
});
```

Don't forget to inject the service in the controller or the app file, if it's not done already.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I've actually used that approach before but it caused problems. My current method works when serving a list of all the results, just need to modify it to serve a specific result.

Comment: I'll get this error when trying your code. 
Error: [$resource:badcfg] array
I've asked for a solution to this before and used the method above, which works for returning all the results.